# How can I Replace 0 with group mean value in sas or sql?

Tags: sql, sas

I want to replace all 0.0 with mean value of particular month

```
value   date      month year
33.2    01SEP2016   9   2016
33.7    02SEP2016   9   2016
34.8    03SEP2016   9   2016
33.8    04SEP2016   9   2016
33.7    05SEP2016   9   2016
33.8    06SEP2016   9   2016
32.7    07SEP2016   9   2016
33.4    08SEP2016   9   2016
32.5    09SEP2016   9   2016
33.7    10SEP2016   9   2016
32.7    11SEP2016   9   2016
32.5    12SEP2016   9   2016
32.1    13SEP2016   9   2016
32.2    14SEP2016   9   2016
32.0    15SEP2016   9   2016
31.8    16SEP2016   9   2016
31.8    17SEP2016   9   2016
31.9    18SEP2016   9   2016
32.5    19SEP2016   9   2016
32.5    20SEP2016   9   2016
32.3    21SEP2016   9   2016
32.6    22SEP2016   9   2016
14.2    23SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     24SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     25SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     26SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     27SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     28SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     29SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     30SEP2016   9   2016
```

Comment: find mean value of month first and then merge it back to the original table and if there is a value 0.0 then replace it with mean value

Comment: And there is another scenario where i need to take average of last three occurrence.. so what will be process for that ?? For ex. i have 0 value in "24 sept 2016 " then i need to take average of 23,22,21 sept.

Comment: What about the subsequent days, e.g. 27th,28th etc, where there are currently no values for the previous 3 days?

Comment: So, for date = '30SEP2016' what 3 previous values do you want?

Comment: Would you be able to update question and things tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your question is pretty easy.  First change the zero values to missing, then use `proc stdsize` to change the missing values to the mean of the month.

```
/* create initial dataset */
data have;
input value   date :date9. month year;
format date date9.;
datalines;
33.2    01SEP2016   9   2016
33.7    02SEP2016   9   2016
34.8    03SEP2016   9   2016
33.8    04SEP2016   9   2016
33.7    05SEP2016   9   2016
33.8    06SEP2016   9   2016
32.7    07SEP2016   9   2016
33.4    08SEP2016   9   2016
32.5    09SEP2016   9   2016
33.7    10SEP2016   9   2016
32.7    11SEP2016   9   2016
32.5    12SEP2016   9   2016
32.1    13SEP2016   9   2016
32.2    14SEP2016   9   2016
32.0    15SEP2016   9   2016
31.8    16SEP2016   9   2016
31.8    17SEP2016   9   2016
31.9    18SEP2016   9   2016
32.5    19SEP2016   9   2016
32.5    20SEP2016   9   2016
32.3    21SEP2016   9   2016
32.6    22SEP2016   9   2016
14.2    23SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     24SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     25SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     26SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     27SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     28SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     29SEP2016   9   2016
0.0     30SEP2016   9   2016
;
run;

/* replace zeros with missing */
data have;
modify have;
call missing(value);
where value=0;
run;

/* replace missing with mean of month */
proc stdize data=have out=want
            method=mean reponly;
by month year;
var value;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `proc sql` to generate a new result set:

```
proc sql;
    select (case when t.value = 0 then t2.avg_value else value end) as value,
           t.date, t.month, t.year
    from t left join
         (select year, month, avg(value) as avg_value
          from t
          group by year, month
         ) t2
         on t.year = t2.year and t.month = t2.month;
```

If you want to phrase this as an `update`, then I would use a correlated subquery:

```
proc sql;
    update t
        set value = (select avg(t2.value)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.value <> 0 and
                           t2.year = t.year and t2.month = t.month
                    )
        where value = 0;
```

Comment: I believe you need to add a `where` clause to the subquery so that it doesn't include zeros in the mean calculation (it's not totally clear from the question, but it doesn't make much sense to include them).  Also, your update statement doesn't work as you can't reference a table being updated in the subquery

Comment: @Longfish . . . I don't have SAS on hand right now to test.  Does it really have that limitation?  As far as I know, the only database with that limitation is MySQL.

Comment: Yes it does!  The error message says you can't reopen the table for update access because it is in use already.  This suggests it runs the subquery first (which makes sense), but keeps the table open, therefore preventing the update